# Edit a bad question by adding context and changing the example given

Tags: discussion, edits

I kinda had a discussion this morning with a moderator who edited a bad question in such a way that for me, he gave the answer at once as well.

For me, the question itself is no longer a question, it's a question answered by an edit.

Now I did discuss it with the mod inside the edits, but I would still like to get some confirmation of what should have been done.

After all the comments back and forth, I still flagged the post because I felt the edit was incorrect

The question can be found here: [How to use enableObjectResizing in designMode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43961413/how-to-use-enableobjectresizing-in-designmode)

Comment: If people feel my edit was inappropriate, feel free to revert it. Editing a question's code *is* often to be avoided. I thought it was acceptable in this case, to try to salvage the question as it was likely about to be closed. I *think* the material I added matches the author's intent (as commented). I may be mistaken. I don't think the question was answered by my edit: when I run the code, I see the same thing as the original author described. An explanation of why could be a useful answer to me.

Comment: How about we wait for the author to respond?

Comment: @Braiam Sure, though I doubt he will have anything to add. For example, his original post didn't even contain [`document.designMode = 'on'`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43961413/revisions). I think that in part is a larger change, as code got added to the question, which @JeremyBanks couldn't have known that the poster knew this (well except for the title perhaps ^_^;;) I don't want to be overly critical here, but I personally had cases where I editted a question and it got reverted because I fixed code unwittingly

Comment: Well, if the post went from "sucks so hard" to "doesn't suck so hard" I'm not opposed. The opposite on the other hand...